# Arduino NodeMCU - ESP8266 - Touch Screens

Tags: arduino, esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266, touchscreen

I've an Arduino project to do and I need a recommendation for Touch Screens at least 2.4 inch that compitable with esp8266.

Also for your attention please, my project include finger print sensor so I need enough free ports for the touch screen and for the finger print sensor.

Thank you for your time and your help :)
Marom Asraf.

[This Is The NodeMCU ESP8266](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0672/9409/products/NodeMCU_ESP8266_development_board_1024x1024.jpg?v=1464135546)

[This Is The NodeMCU ESP8266 With Ports Names](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dlnya-Aziz/publication/327070645/figure/fig2/AS:660563264819201@1534501963642/ESP8266-Node-MCU-Module.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be this touchscreen:
Walfront 2.4 inch 240 x 320

As a library you can use this with an ESP8266:
https://github.com/Bodmer/TFT_eSPI

Comment: Thank you for answer :)
Before I'll order it , do you sure that will be compitable also with the fingerprint sensor ?

I mean if I'll connect this display to the ESP8266 I'll still have enough ports for the fingerprint sensor ?

Comment: it should. i think the fingerprint sensor get connected over the rx (gpio 3) and the tx (gpio 1) ports. The Touch Display have to connected over SPI. You can see a possible connection here: https://nailbuster.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/MyTouchSPIShield.png

Comment: Thank you so MUCH sir ☺

you are very helpful for me

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/-/he/dp/B073R7BH1B/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=walfront+2.4+inch+240x320+display&qid=1614162590&sr=8-1



This one can shipped to my country. This is the display I need ?

Comment: i think so. it seems that this person tries the same like you. it shoul dbe the same touchscreen with the ILI9341 driver. https://simple-circuit.com/esp8266-nodemcu-ili9341-tft-display/